# C: How to correctly extract the binary content from a HTTP response

Tags: c, http-headers, stdout

I'm trying to build a simple TCP HTTP client that gets the url of an image as the argument, downloads it and writes it to stdout, so that it can then be piped to a file.

The download in my program seems to be working correctly, but I can't get the extraction of the HTTP content and the writing to stdout to work. Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define RESP_BUF_SIZE 2000000

void extract_http_body(char *resp_buf, char *data) {
    data = strstr(resp_buf, "\r\n\r\n") + 4;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int sockfd, received;
    char host[BUF_SIZE], path[BUF_SIZE], send_buf[BUF_SIZE], resp_buf[RESP_BUF_SIZE], data[RESP_BUF_SIZE];
    char HTTP_PORT[3] = "80";
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;

    /* SOCKET STUFF HERE, WORKS FINE */

    /* Recv response */
    if ((received = recv(sockfd, resp_buf, RESP_BUF_SIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Error while receiving response.");
        exit(1);
    }
    resp_buf[received] = '\0';

    extract_http_body(resp_buf, data);

    fwrite(data, strlen(data), 1, stdout);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhKNW.jpg) image for testing, which is 43kB and should thus fit comfortably into the buffer.

Would be great if someone could set me on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function here:

```
void extract_http_body(char *resp_buf, char *data) {
    data = strstr(resp_buf, "\r\n\r\n") + 4;
}
```

will just set the local `data` variable to the return value of `strstr`. You will not see this value outside of the function.
You could return the value:

```
char* extract_http_body(char *resp_buf) {
    return strstr(resp_buf, "\r\n\r\n") + 4;
}
```

or pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
void extract_http_body(char *resp_buf, char **data) {
    *data = strstr(resp_buf, "\r\n\r\n") + 4;
}
```

Then, you declared `data` as an array in `main()`. This would require you to copy the content from `resp_buf` to `data`, which is not necessary. Instead you could declare `data` as a `char*`, and use the above to just set it to the beginning of the data inside `resp_buf`, and avoid the needless copy.

Comment: I've tried your second suggestion, returned the `char*` from `strstr` and stored it in a `char *data;`. This works fine with text bodies, yet the image is still corrupted (the file size is much smaller than it should be). Could it be a problem with `fwrite(data, strlen(data), 1, stdout);`? I've also tried `fwrite(data, sizeof(*data), 1, stdout);`, but to no avail.

Comment: Yes, it's most likely because the image data contains zero-bytes, so `strlen` will stop when it finds the first one. Use `received` to calculate the number of valid bytes, like `write_len = received - (data - resp_buf)` for example. (Check if `data` is not null first, in case there is no cr-lf-cr-lf).